# laravel 5.2 user login redirect with condition

Tags: redirect, controller, conditional-statements, laravel-5

I am making Dating website using laravel 5.2

I have Tables in database

### --user

### --profile

### --education

### --Occupation

### --Marital Status

### --Parents Details

Each of the table has user_id as forigen key of User table.

All models have been created and hasMany and belongsTo relation has been added respectively.

My question is when user login, I would like user to land to specific create controller if table is unfilled or form is not filled. For EX- profile.create, education.create , occupation.create.

Or is there any efficient way I can handle this situation.

Thanks in advance, I hope you got it. Let me know if you still need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple idea below:

- Create a column `full_profile` (tinyint, length 1) in your table which indicates the profile is full. Default it's `0`.
- After a validations are `true`, set the value of the `full_profile` to `1`.

> Ok, now it's simple:

- User logs in
- Check the value of `full_profile`. If `0`, redirect to form, if `1`, redirect to dashboard?